# Guava : LinkedHashMultimap values as list and not String

Tags: guava

I was reading about Guava's `LinkedHashMultimap` and thought it might be useful to me.

I have a requirement such that I have a map as follows:

```
Key:Value
A    B
A    C
A    D
P    Q
P    R
```

If above is the input in my map, then I want to use `LinkedHashMultimap` to create a map like:

```
Key : Value 
A     List<B,C,D>
P     List<Q,R>
```

Tried using `LinkedHashMultimap` but it has following issue:

```
    mapLen.entries().stream().forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println("mapTemp2 key + " + entry.getKey());
        System.out.println("mapTemp2 value + " + entry.getValue());
    });
```

Above prints the `String` values in the map and not `List<String>`.

Can someone pointout how it can be done.

(Kindly note: I am aware of normal core java solution of iterating, checking and the creating list and inserting into map.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we can see in javadoc, [`Multimap#entries()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#entries()) returns `Collection<Map.Entry<K,V>>` - so basically, you iterate over each key/value pair, instead of key/(value set). To do so, try turning `Multimap<K, V>` to standard `Map<K, List<V>>`. You can do that with [`Multimap#asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap()), so your code would look like:

```
mapLen.asMap().entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println("mapTemp2 key + " + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("mapTemp2 value + " + entry.getValue());
});
```

PS. I guess you missed parenthesis after `...entries` - it's a method, not a property, so you should have used:

```
//            vv DOWN HERE
mapLen.entries().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println("mapTemp2 key + " + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("mapTemp2 value + " + entry.getValue());
});
```

Comment: That's what I'm here for ;) It's custom to accept the answer that satisfies your needs; see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer I also recommend going through the whole Help section at least once, it's not that long and makes life on SO easier.